# Facebook API not returning message_tags to application

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have created an application using the facebook API.  With the application I plan on getting the user feed of the authenticated users. I have set the extended permissions read_stream so I know that's not the problem. I have checked in the graph explorer by running the following query:

```
/me/feed?fields=id,message,message_tags,likes.fields(id,name),created_time,shares,from&limit=3000
```

When I run the above query in the graph explorer it returns everything I request just fine but when I run the following query with the PHP SDK in my application it doesn't return the message_tags

Here is the query:

```
$user_feed = $facebook->api("/{$user['userId']}/feed?fields=id,message,message_tags,likes.fields(id,name),created_time,shares,from&limit=3000&access_token={$user['accessToken']}");
```

And yes I have a valid accessToken and userId, because when I put this query in the graph explorer it return everything like it should.

So, my question is that why isn't everything being returned when I query from my application?

Thanks.

PS: I have one file authenticating the user for the app and another file using the userId and accessToken to get the data of that user ... The above problem is in the separate file that im using to get the user data

Further more I went to the following link and found that it isn't giving the proper results...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/MyUserId/feed?fields=id,message,message_tags,likes.fields(id,name),created_time,shares,from&limit=3000&access_token=xxxxxxxx
```

It returns the posts but it doesn't return the likes for most of the posts and doesn't return any of the mention_tags

Comment: Is no one able to reproduce this issue? What can be wrong?

Comment: This must be the first question that didn't receive any comment or answer in more than 24 hours...